# New true/false DataFrame based on another DataFrame with datetime ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem that I can't solve for a long time. I want to generate new DataFrame with interpolated values (every one minute), and N additional columns, where N is length of set from ID column in base DataFrame.

My DataFrame (**df**) looks like this:

```
Datetime_ON           Datetime_OFF          ID
2020-01-02 15:21:49   2020-01-02 15:32:44   GB5U
2020-01-02 15:22:40   2020-01-02 15:24:14   GS8U
2020-01-02 15:45:25   2020-01-02 15:59:18   GS8U
2020-01-02 16:07:11   2020-01-02 16:16:50   GB5U
```

Now I want to create a new DataFrame (**new_df**) with interpolated values with datetime range from `min(df['Datetime_ON'])` to `max(df['Datetime_OFF'])`

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=min(df['Datetime_ON']), end=max(df['Datetime_OFF']), freq="1min"))
```

---

```
Datetime
2020-01-02 15:21:00
2020-01-02 15:22:00
2020-01-02 15:23:00
...
2020-01-02 16:16:00
```

Now I want to add N columns from set of **ID** column from **df** DrataFrame `set(df['ID'])` and put in that columns **True/False** or **1/0** value based on condition if **Datetime** column from **new_df** is between **Datetime_ON** and **Datetime_OFF** from **df** in any row with **ID** equal column name in **new_df**

My expected output:

```
Datetime              GB5U   GS8U
2020-01-02 15:21:00   False  False
2020-01-02 15:22:00   True   False
2020-01-02 15:23:00   True   True
2020-01-02 15:24:00   True   True
2020-01-02 15:25:00   True   False
...
2020-01-02 16:15:00   True   False
2020-01-02 16:16:00   True   False
```

The problem is that my dataframe has over 700k rows, and length of ID set is more than 100 (more than 100 new columns). I tried to use iterrows() and apply function but it is extremely slow. Is there a way to solve that problem in reasonable time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First attempt

Here's a suggestion. I'm not sure if it's actually faster than what you've already tried, but maybe worth a try:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

# Just to make new_df as in the example
new_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2020-01-02 15:21:00',
                                    '2020-01-02 16:16:00',
                                    freq="1min"),
                                    columns=['Datetime'])

# To make the following statement more compact
df.rename(columns={'Datetime_ON': 'ON', 'Datetime_OFF': 'OFF'}, inplace=True)

new_df = pd.concat(
        [new_df]
        + [
            (reduce(or_,((start <= new_df) & (new_df <= stop)
                         for start, stop in zip(group['ON'], group['OFF'])))
                    .rename({'Datetime': key}, axis='columns'))            
            for key, group in df.groupby('ID')
          ],
        axis='columns'
    ).set_index('Datetime', drop=True)
```

Result:

```
                      GB5U   GS8U
Datetime                         
2020-01-02 15:21:00  False  False
2020-01-02 15:22:00   True  False
2020-01-02 15:23:00   True   True
2020-01-02 15:24:00   True   True
2020-01-02 15:25:00   True  False
...
2020-01-02 16:15:00   True  False
2020-01-02 16:16:00   True  False
```

---

#### Second attempt

I thought a bit more about this problem and might have found a faster way. The idea is to set the `True` values more straight forward:

```py
# new_df as in the example
new_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2020-01-02 15:21:00',
                                    '2020-01-02 16:16:00',
                                    freq="1min"),
                                    columns=['Datetime'])

# To make the following statement more compact
df.rename(columns={'Datetime_ON': 'ON', 'Datetime_OFF': 'OFF'}, inplace=True)

# To make sure the columns are in datetime format
df.ON = pd.to_datetime(df.ON)
df.OFF = pd.to_datetime(df.OFF)

idx = new_df.Datetime
dfs = []
for key, group in df.groupby('ID'):
    trues = [
                minute
                for start, stop in zip(group.ON, group.OFF)
                for minute in pd.date_range(start.ceil('min'), stop.floor('min'), freq='1min')
            ]
    df_group = pd.DataFrame({key: False}, index=idx)
    df_group.loc[trues, key] = True
    dfs.append(df_group)

new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis='columns')
```

For the example the results are identical. And I think that should be the case in general, but I'm not yet a 100% sure. And, again, I'm also not sure about the efficiency because a lot depends on the real data.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution and it's faster than apply function (now I need 1h to execute this on my data set).

Comment: @aozk Puh, that's still a pretty long time. How long did it take before?

Comment: About 3 hours. I can't believe there is no solution to solve that much faster.

Comment: @aozk I have added a second attempt. Maybe it's better.